# problem with print command involving mixing integer and strings

Tags: python

I want to print a list of ordinal numbers with the appropriate suffix attached (i.e 1st, 2nd...). The issue seems to be with the print command. As you can see below, I've commented all IF blocks except for the first to try troubleshooting.  Thanks.

```
ord_nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for ord_num in ord_nums:
    if (ord_num == 1):
        print(ord_num + "st")
    elif (ord_num == 2):
        print(ord_num) #+ "nd")
    elif (ord_num == 3):
        print (ord_num) #+ "rd")
    else:
        print(ord_num) #+ "th")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you elaborate on the precise issue you are encountering? At a glance, I'm guessing you're receiving a `TypeError` for attempting to add a `str` and an `int`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast it to a string first before adding; you are trying to add an int to a string

```
print(str(ord_num) + "st")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to cast each `integer` into `string` in the `print` statement. For example -

```
print(str(ord_num) + "st")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you got a `TypeError` for adding a `str` and an `int`. The correct code would be `print(str(ord_num) + "st")`.

Answer (score 0):

To mix types in a string to print, you can use a formatted string by using `f"str"` and put the variables you want to print between brackets like this :

```py
a = 3
b = "b"

print(f"This is a number : {a}")
print(f"This is a string : {b}")
```